# EXT js 4.2 How to filter grid with filter plugin on key press?

Tags: extjs, filter, grid, extjs4.2, ext.net

I tried to find something to filter my grid when I write anything in the text inputs for the filterHeader and press enter for ex. Couldn't find anything about it, thankful for any ideas?

Regards;

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is included in the framework. Check this [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/example/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html) on [Sencha Docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I know that it's included, but it still goes on updatebuffer time, not on keypress, you can try it with Enter-key. Thanks anyway.